# Line diagram using unique combinations of data frame

Tags: r

I have one response variable which is continous and six output variables. Out of six output variables four of them are categorical.

I needed to plot a line diagram with the every unique combinations of data frame consisting from categorical variables with respect to x and y.

Please help me.